# How to use C# Steeltoe Library to connect to an existing ZUUL server?

Tags: c#, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, steeltoe

I'm currently using Steeltoe C# library/API to connect a Restful API/Eureka client to an Eureka service. I also have running a ZUUL service.

I'm trying to understand how my Restful API will connect to ZUUL using Steeltoe?

I have read most of the documentation on the Steeltoe.io site, but it does not mention how to connect to ZUUL.

```
No code yet, other than my Restful API sample I'm testing with.
I can provide that code if needed.
```

I'm looking for advice on making use of Steeltoe to connect to ZUUL.